# Android and Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

Im trying to implement GA in my android app. When i call 'GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance()' i get a force close in the emulator and the stacktrace 'ERROR/dalvikvm(588): Could not find method GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance'. Im compiling against Android 1.6.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that `libGoogleAnalytics.jar` isn't in your APK file? It should be placed in the `/libs` directory.

Comment: I have added that, and can compile. Its at runtime the problem exists.

Comment: Sure, but it's possible that your compile environment is pointing to the jar file but it's not part of the APK; that would cause it to compile but not run.

Comment: That might be it, will check. Thanks